# ADB2C - Microsoft Graph Query Users based on email domain

Tags: graph, filter, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, odata

I want to query ADB2C using Microsoft Graph for users on issuerAssignedId with value on domain name example all users with issuerAssignedId with domain name @yahoo.com,  does anyone know how to do that?

There is an example for one specific email:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=displayName,id&$filter=identities/any(c:c/issuerAssignedId eq 'maxdude@yahoo.com' and c/issuer eq 'contoso.onmicrosoft.com')
```

Cheers
Maqsood.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Graph `$filter` query parameter doesn't support `contains` or `endwith` operators based on [filter parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter) and my tests.

So I'm afraid that we cannot get all users with `issuerAssignedId` with domain name `@yahoo.com` directly using Microsoft Graph.

You need to get all the users and handle them in code to filter with users. In short, you need to use additional third-party filter methods.