# Register accounts by domain on Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-ad-b2c, customization, registration

I need to identify people in organization when they're registering in my app through Azure AD B2C.

I mean, if a user register a new account with:

```
user1@org1.com
```

and a new user tries to register a new account with:

```
user2@org1.com
```

The Azure AD B2C flow would reject the register and `user1@org1.com` need to approve the register

Answer (score 0):

There's no nice way to do this with just B2C as it is only really meant to get information on a single user at a time and there's no good way to look up if a specific email domain is inside your tenant from B2C.

You'll need an external application with an API to do most of the work. You can then use the information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-api-connector?pivots=b2c-user-flow) to set up the communication between B2C and your application

Comment: Thank you for quick response @Christian Le Breton

Comment: I'm trying to obtain users email domains through Function App and Azure Function connected to Graph API with Application permissions. But when querying the /users endpoint i'm trying to use the ``filter`` param but not works the function endWith on AD B2C tenants. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62488145/adb2c-microsoft-graph-query-users-based-on-email-domain

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not too familiar with the Graph API, and it seems like this may be difficult to do using just that. 

You may just want to store the list of already registered domains elsewhere, along with an associated approval person for that domain. I'd recommend referring to the approval person by ObjectID in this app, rather than email as that just makes it easier to make sure their email is up to date everywhere, as well as reducing potential places personal information may leak.